# Run time installation directory of debian package contents

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, dpkg

I have a debian package that I built that contains a tar ball of the files, a control file, and a postinst file.  Its built using dpkg-deb and it installs properly using dpkg.

The modification I would like to make is to have the installation directory of the files be determined at runtime based on an environment variable that will be set when dpkg -i is run on the deb file.  I echo out the environment variable in the postinst script and I can see that its set properly.

My questions:

1) Is it possible to dynamically determine the installation directory at runtime?

2) If its possible how would I go about this?  I have read about the rules file and the mypackage.install files but I don't know if either of these would allow me to accomplish this.

I could hack it by copying the files to the target location in the posinst script but I would prefer to do it the right way if possible.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is an option you can pass to `dpkg` to use a different root than `/usr` for installation. `deb` packages don't have an "installation directory" in  that sense - it would help if you added examples of what you have now and what you would like it to be. In theory you could move around stuff from your `postinst` script but I would strongly discourage you.

Comment: Good idea.  I tried using --instdir= and it copied the files but postinst would not run since --instdir does a chroot so you have to have the dpkg admin directory there also.  I also tried using --root and --admindir in combination to see if I could split the two directories.  rpm has a relocate flag so you can move the location of the package.  I have to have a dynamic directory since this package must live in different locations on two different embedded linux distributions.  As for an example, just assume a single file in a tarball that live in different spots on different machines.

Comment: I would simply create two different `deb` packages, unless the file is a conffile. Examples would still help. A typical package-managed file would be something like `/usr/lib/yourpackage.so` and a typical conffile e.g. `/etc/yourpackage.cfg`.

Comment: Maybe also look at the "alternatives" facility, although it's mainly useful in the opposite direction (two unrelated packages want to control the destination of a symlink in an agreed standard location).

Comment: I can create two packages no problem.  The issue is that the code in the package is all common and needs to be installed on 6 various embedded platforms where the installs are all in different locations.  More specifically some of the directory structures don't exist on some of the platforms.  This would mean managing 6 different packages instead of 1.  Still researching at this point.  Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

So this is what I found out about this problem over the past couple of weeks.

With prepackaged binaries you can't build a debian package with a destination directory dynamicall determined at runtime.  I believe that this might be possible if installing a package that is built from source where you can set the install directory using configure.  But in this case since these are embedded Ubuntu machines they don't have make so I didn't pursue such an option.  I did work out a non traditional method (hack) for installing that did work.  Since debian packages simply contain a tar ball relative to / simply build your package relative to a directory under /tmp.  In the postinst script you can then determine where to copy the files from the archive into a permanent location.

I expected that after rebooting and the automatic deletion of the subdirectory under /tmp that dpkg might not know that the file package existed.  This wasn't a problem.  When I ran 'dpkg -l myapp' it showed as still installed.  Updating the package using dpkg/apt-get also worked without a hitch.

What I did find is that if you attempted to remove the package using 'dpkg -r myapp' that dpkg would try and remove /tmp which wasn't good.  However /tmp isn't easily removed so it never succeeded.  Plus in our situation we never remove packages but instead simply upgrade them.

I eventually had to abandon the universal package due to code differences in the sources resulting in having to recompile per platform but I would have left it this way and it did work.

I tried using --instdir to change the install directory of the package and it does relocate the files but dpkg fails since the dpkg file can't be found relative to the new instdir.  Using --instdir is sort of like a chroot.  I also tried --admindir and --root in various combinations to see if I could use the dpkg system relative to / but install relocate the files but they didn't work.  I guess rpm has a relocate option that works but not Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

You can also write a script that runs dpkg-deb with a different environment for 6 times, generating 6 different packages. When you make a modification, you simply have to run your script, and all 6 packages gets generated and you can install them on your machines avoiding postinst hacking!

Answer (score 0):

Why not install to a standard location, and simply use a postinst script to create symbolic links to the desired location? This is much cleaner, and shouldn't break anything in dpk -I.